# Database design for complex music analytics

Tags: python, data-modeling

I'm a researcher studying animal behavior, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure my data. I present short musical tunes to animals and record their responses.

**The Data**

Each tune consists of 1-10 notes randomly chosen from major + minor scales spanning several octaves. Each note is played for a fixed duration but played randomly within some short time window.

I then record the animal's binary response to the tune (like / dislike).

I play >500 tunes to the animal each day, for >300 days. I also combine data from >10 animals.

I also need to store variables such as trial number on each day (was it the 1st tune presented? last? etc.), and date so that I know what data points to exclude due to external issues (e.g. animal stopped responding after 100 trials or for the entire day).

**The Analysis**

I'm trying to uncover what sorts of musical structure in these randomly generated tunes will lead to likes/dislikes from the animal. I do this in a mostly hypothesis-driven manner, based on previous research. The queries I need to perform on my dataset are of the form: "does having more notes from the same octave increase likeability of the tune?"

I'm also performing analysis on the dataset throughout the year as data is being accumulated.

**What I've tried**

I combine data from all animals into a single gigantic list containing dicts. Each dict represents a single trial and its associated:

- animal ID#
- session ID#
- trial ID#
- binary response (like/dislike)
- tune, which is defined by a dict. The keys are simply the notes played, and the values denote when the note is played. E.g. `{'1A#':[30,100]}` means a tune with just a single note, A# from 1st octave, played from 30ms to 100ms.

I save this to a single pickle file. Every day after all the animals are done, I update the pickle file. I run my data analysis roughly once per week by loading the updated pickle file.

I've been looking to re-structure my data into a database or Pandas DataFrame format because of speed of 1) serializing data and 2) querying, and 3) possible cleaner code instead of dealing with nested dicts. I initially thought that my data would naturally lend itself well to some table structure because of the trial-by-trial structure of my experiment. Unfortunately, the definition of tunes within the table seems tricky, as the tunes don't really have some fixed structure.

What would be possible alternatives in structuring my data?

Comment: I would use a relational database and record each element of a tune in a separate column, i.e. note1, note2, note3, octave, duration, time played, animal played to, etc. Should lead to a cleaner code and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the hard part of the problem is that you'll probably want the stimulus (tune) data formatted differently for different queries. What I would think about doing is making a relatively simple data structure for your stimuli (tunes) and add a unique identifier to each unique tune. You could probably get away with using your dictionary structures here if your structure can fit into memory.

Then I would put your trials into a relational database with the corresponding stimulus IDs. Each trial entry in the database would have complete subject and session information.

Your for each analysis permutation you will do two steps to get the relevant data:

1. Filter the stimuli using the stimulus data structure and get a list of their corresponding IDs.
2. Preform a query on your trials database to get the trials with this list IDs. You can add other parameters to your query, obviously, to filter based on subject, session, etc.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

I would use a relational database that has JSON support, for example, postgresql. That way, you can store the tune as a JSON object and not have to worry about the structure of the tune. The rest of your data model seems relational. I'd create table for animals, and then a table for trials/sessions. So your session table might look like

```
SessionId (integer, primary key) | TrialId (integer) | AnimalId (integer, foreign key) | tune (json) | response (bool)
```